# How to put red asterisk in front of each required field in phalcon

Tags: php, html, phalcon

Do any one know how to put asterisk(*) in front of mandatory fields of a form.

I have lots of fields in the form I want put a red asterisk in front of required field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no privilege in phalcon, Only it Database fields will have mandatory if they have defined as `Not NULL`.

But If you want to show the * or astric mark then you need to add only CSS or simply add * to the label filed.

But you can assign a parameter from form controller as `'isRequired'` and then check in the volt file the if element does have this value as true then show the * mark otherwise not.

As below:

```
{{ element.getAttribute('isRequired') ? '<span class="required"></span>' : '' }}
```

And in the css file define a classs as below:

```
.required {
  content: "*";
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

Hope you will get the answer. It worked for me.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am looking for a solution that we can made in controller only.

Comment: I dont think so that there is any field or pericular param is there to do the same, you have to use the html or css only.

Comment: Thanks @Garry , This worked for me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hey Aman, If you found that this solution worked, then please mark it as accepted. @AmanGarg

Answer (score 4):

You can add a css class:

```
label.required::after {
  content: "*";
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: You are right, but I am looking for a solution in phalcon.

Comment: You can create a [custom render layout](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.1/reference/forms.html#rendering-forms) for your form elements. But either way, using the above CSS method is the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a custom attribute to your form elements and than check its value in you view. In the example bellow I set an attribute called "isRequired" to true in every element that should be required

```
        $name = new Text('name',['placeholder' => 'Your Name', 'isRequired' => true]);
        $name->setFilters(['striptags', 'trim']);
        $name->setLabel("Name");
        $this->add($name);
```

Than in the view I check if its value it true so I can set the * character.
The example bellow uses dynamic form rendering but it works the same if you statically write down all of your form elements.

```
   {%for element in form.getElements()%}
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
          {{form.render(element.GetName())}}
          <label for="{{element.GetName()}}">
            {{element.GetLabel()}}
            {{ element.getAttribute('isRequired') ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' }}
          </label>
        </div>
     </div>
   {%endfor%}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but its not fulfilling my requirement, actually 'isRequired' is used for validation that would be appear after form submission, but i want to show the text field as required either with the estrick (*) mark or something else before submitting the form so that user could be able to understand that which fields are mandatory and which are not